# How to get from tmap the latitude longitude of each x,y point on the World map?

Tags: latitude-longitude, tmap

With the library tmap, a map can be plotted of the world coastlines and borders:

```
library(tmap)
data("World")
tm_shape(World) + tm_borders()
```

Is it possible to get the latitude longitude of each x,y point on the map that is used to draw coastlines and borders?

If not, is such a set of data with latitude longitude points of the world map to draw coastlines (and borders) available elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)

data("World")
tm_shape(World) + tm_borders()

Test <- st_union(World)

tm_shape(Test) + tm_borders()

Test_coord <- st_cast(Test, "MULTIPOINT")

tm_shape(Test_coord) + tm_dots()
```

There are some lines and points in the file that are not coastal lines. I think that is so because of some problmes in the World object, so condier using a different shape file.

Comment: Dear Orlando,

Many thanks for your time and effort to answer my question. I ran your code just fine.
I try to export the result (Test_coord) and get the following error:

`The object "dataframe" must have class data.frame`

Forgive me my ignorance, but you would help me great when you show me how to do this.

Best,
Eric

Comment: Eric, which function are you using? as Test_coord is still an spatial object you should export it as such. Try st_write(Test_coord, "Test.shp")

Comment: Dear Orlando, yes, this actually does the job real fine!
I got the  latitude longitude points of the world map exported to a shape file and I am able to work with that further.
Again, many thanks for your kind assistance.

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Do not forget to upvote the answer and marked it as solved :)